# ReactJS - Unexpected token, expected }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm fairly new to ReactJS and using Babel, please bear with me if it is a stupid question. I am running the code snippet below, and the babel per-proccessor is giving me an error about the curly bracket right after the render. It seems to think that before i can have that that, i need to close the curly bracket opened from my class. I cant seem to figure out why.

Run .JSX file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>React App</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

class Greeting extends React.Component {
      render() {
          return (<h1> hi </h1>);
      }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Babel error:

```
SyntaxError: src/header2.jsx: Unexpected token, expected } (20:15)
 18 |
 19 | class Greeting extends React.Component {
>20 |       render() {
    |                ^
 21 |           return (<h1> hi </h1>);
 22 |       }
 23 | }
```

Comment: Try applying the `babel-preset-env` plugin to your babel config

Comment: If you want to play around with Babel in a script tag, you must get [the `babel-standalone` script as well](https://babeljs.io/en/setup#installation) e.g. `<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, here is the link: https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js

Comment: The React Documentation specifically says not to use this, and encourages using the Babel npm preproccesor instead, which is what im using. https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: @djfdev Thanks for the suggestion, it didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this cdn after react

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>`

you need babel to run JSX files,  more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)

Comment: The React Documentation specifically says not to use this, and encourages using the Babel npm preproccesor instead, which is what im using.

Comment: Sure, your right but I think he wants to play around without configuration environment but I shared a link where explain how to implement babel using `npm install` as well with more details

Comment: No, ive played around with it already. Though i appreciate the help. The link you sent is the link i followed to get it setup this far, and has led to my current question :)